# How to add the CryptoJS into maven that used for Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, cryptojs

I used CryptoJS libraries (Downloaded and placed under lib folder in Jmeter) in Jmeter JSR223 Sampler using load directive.

```
load('crypto-js-3.1.9/crypto-js.js');

function AESEncryption(text, passphase, bytessize) {

var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('ABCDEFGHIJKL1234567891234');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1234567890123456');
var blocksize = bytessize / 2;
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), passphase, key,
{
    keySize: bytessize,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
var dta = String(encrypted);
return dta;}


function AESDecryption(text, key, bytessize) {
try {
    //alert(text + ":" + key + ":" + bytessize);
    var e = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, key, bytessize);
    //alert("Ec:" + e);
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, key, bytessize).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
catch (Error) {
    return "";}}
```

I just want to integrate this JMX file into MAVEN com.lazerycode.jmeter.Plugin. I just copied the JMX file into src/test/jmeter folder but when I tried to run the script from CLI using mvn install its failing to load the Crypto module (Actullay I just copied the JMX file and I'm not sure where I should place this CryptoJS into maven folder).

Let me know where should I keep this CryptoJS that will work in maven environment.

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.paypal</groupId>
    <artifactId>AMAZON_P2P</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AMAZON_P2P</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ttps://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>  
                   <propertiesUser>                    
                       <threadCount>${performancetest.threadCount}</threadCount>  
                       <testIterations>${performancetest.testIterations}</testIterations>                      
                    </propertiesUser>  
                     <propertiesJMeter>                    
                         <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>  
                         <jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count>   
                    </propertiesJMeter> 
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below lines does the magic:

```
<jmeterExtensions>
          <artifact>org.webjars.bower:crypto-js:3.1.9</artifact>
 </jmeterExtensions>
```